# Does having integer calculation improve the performance than real value calculation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am experimenting some graphics functions which I learned at the class. In the book, it says that integer calculation improves performance in C++. But I am doing it on JavaScript. Does it matter in Javascript?

On Chrome, it runs smoothly. Not surprisingly, its performance decreases significantly in Firefox 19 and IE10

```
function circ(cx, cy, rad, color){  //Using second-order differential
            var x = 0;
            var y = rad;
            var d = 1 - rad;
            var deltaE = 3;
            var deltaSE = -2*rad+5;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ptc(cx,cy,x,y);
            while(y>x){
                if(d<0){                //Select E
                    d+=deltaE;
                    deltaE +=2;
                    deltaSE +=2;
                }
                else{                   //Select SE
                    d+=deltaSE;
                    deltaE+=2;
                    deltaSE+=4;
                    y--;
                }
                x++;
                ptc(cx,cy,x,y);
            }
            ctx.stroke();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with very large fractions then sure, the simpler the numbers the faster it'll run, but the less smooth any animation based on that number will be.

Comment: my calculation is based on mouse movement. then integer coordinates of mouse are used only for addition. I guess there is no real value in calculation.

Comment: Yeah if you are doing x, y coordinates from mouse movement don't worry about using another other than an integer value.

Comment: thanks. I was just experimenting this thing. Apparently, the performance of html5 canvas.arc is way better than above function. it is fun, though :)